# Link <a> tag downloading the default HTML page when condition is not fulfilled

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a weird problem. I have a link tag to download like

```
     <div class="col-md-4 about-right">
         <ul>
        <h5>Get My Cv</h5>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"><input type="radio"class="rad" id="radio1" name="optradio"></span>Download In PDF</li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"><input type="radio" class="rad" id="radio2" name="optradio"></span>Download In Word Doc</li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"><input type="radio" class="rad"id="radio3"name="optradio"></span>Download In HTML</li>
        <center>
        <a href="#" id="cvLink"  download onclick="getCv()">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Download</button></a> 
        </center>
       </ul> 
       </div>
```

Which downloads documents using radio button checked validation.I have also 3 radio button. I change the URL link based on which radio button is clicked and download the documents using JavaScript. But the problem is when any of the radio button is unclicked I want to  show an alert and make the link to do nothing.

I tried this by using `"# , javaScript:void(0)"`. it shows the alert but also downloads the main HTML file on which I am working on. I just want the link will do nothing but show the alert only.

My code is something like below

```
<script>
function getCv() {
    if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
        document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=MZTFCWnRYbnlvclk";
    }   

    else if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked) {
        document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=uK6ct7MZ2N6Ni1qQUFyWXM";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('radio3').checked) {
     document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0VDenJqUldud2M";
    }

    else
    {

     alert('Please Select Any Format To Download!!');
    }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What if your else{} statement returns false? Does that help?

Comment: nope i tried that doesn't work .still downloads the default page

Comment: Are those radio buttons mutually exclusive..meaning only one can be checked instead of all three being checked?

Comment: yes only checked at a time

Comment: Of course you could probably also just add an invisible <a>, have the if statements click that and have the visible <a> really do nothing (i.e. remove the donwload attribute).  OR what happens if you do document.getElementById('cvLink').removeAttribute('download')?

Comment: try to set href value # for else case below the alert msg.                            else {     alert('Please Select Any Format To Download!!'); document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "#";}

Comment: Nope I tried . even with "javaScript:void(0)" it downloads some thing like " NETWORK_INVALID_REQUEST" but I want it to do nothing just show the alert ! @ GSB

Comment: Could you show the relevant ("*[MCVE]*") HTML? I *think* I have an answer, but I can't test my theory without knowing what your HTML is.

Comment: I just tested it out and the approach with the hidden <a> works: <a href="#" id="cvLink" style="display:none;"  download>hidden</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getCv()">click here</a> and then document.getElementById('cvLink').click(); in each of the 3 cases

Comment: @DavidThomas I added everything just changed the url otherwise everything is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before we get to the answer to your question I'd like to take a moment to point out some issues with your HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 about-right">
  <ul>
    <h5>Get My Cv</h5>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
      <input type="radio"class="rad" id="radio1" name="optradio"></span>Download In PDF
    </li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
      <input type="radio" class="rad" id="radio2" name="optradio"></span>Download In Word Doc</li>
    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
    <input type="radio" class="rad"id="radio3"name="optradio"></span>Download In HTML</li>
    <center>
      <a href="#" id="cvLink" download onclick="getCv()">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Download</button>
      </a>
    </center>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, the first problem is one that recurs twice, that the *only* valid direct child element of a `<ul>` (or an `<ol>`) is the `<li>` element. The others you have in there, the `<h5>` and the `<center>` (more on *that* in a moment) are invalid HTML where they're placed here.

You have the option of either removing those elements from the `<ul>`, as I've done, or you can simply wrap them in a parent `<li>` so that the DOM structure becomes valid.

Further, the `<center>` element has been deprecated since HTML 4.1, I think. Regardless of *when* it was deprecated, however, it remains deprecated and should no longer be used. If you should need to center something in your layout use CSS to style the presentation of the document, HTML should only define the structure.

Also, and I think this is the last issue with your HTML, it's invalid HTML to have an interactive element, such as a `<button>`, within another interactive element, such as an `<a>`. In my demo to reproduce your problem I simply discarded the `<button>` element, since it has no `download` attribute.

That said, the following JavaScript is my proposed solution, the HTML is also in the snippet along with the JavaScript and CSS:

```
// a named function to highlight the <input> elements required
// in order to enable the <a> element:
function highlightRequirements(e) {

  // caching the element that initiated the events
  // here the <a> element:
  let clicked = this,

      // retrieving the elements that are required to
      // be chosen amongst before the <a> can be used:
      required = document.querySelectorAll(

        // I store, in the <a> element the attribute:
        // data-required="input[name=optradio]"
        // here we use the HTMLElement.dataset interface
        // to retrieve that selector, which is passed as
        // the argument to document.querySelectorAll:
        clicked.dataset.required
      );

  // if the event type (the event, 'e', is passed automatically
  // from the EventTarget.addEventListener() method) is the
  // 'mouseenter' event:
  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {

    // if the <a> element has the download attribute set:
    if (clicked.download) {

      // we remove the event-listener bound to that element
      // for both 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events:
      this.removeEventListener('mouseenter', highlightRequirements);
      this.removeEventListener('mouseleave', highlightRequirements);

      // and we iterate over the required elements, using
      // Array.prototype.forEach(), and an Arrow function
      // expression, to remove the 'highlight' class from
      // the parentNode of each required ('req') element:
      required.forEach(req => req.parentNode.classList.remove('highlight'));
    } else {

      // if the <a> element does not have the download property,
      // we iterate over the required elements and add the
      // 'highlight' class-name, in order to trigger the animation
      // defined in the CSS, in order to draw the users' attention:
      required.forEach(req => req.parentNode.classList.add('highlight'));
    }

  // otherwise, if the event was not the 'mouseenter' event (and so
  // must be the 'mouseleave' event):
  } else {

    // we iterate over the required elements, and remove the 'highlight'
    // class-name from their parentNodes:
    required.forEach(req => req.parentNode.classList.remove('highlight'));
  }
}

// a named function, fired by the radio inputs, to
// 'enable' or 'activate' the <a> element:
function linkActivate(e) {

  // we use document.querySelector to retrieve the first
  // - if any - element matching the supplied selector:
  var link = document.querySelector(

    // similarly to above, I stored the selector for the
    // relevant <a> element in the 'data-link' attribute,
    // and retrieve that attribute-value using the
    // HTMLElement.dataset interface:
    this.dataset.link
  );

  // setting the download attribute to 'true':
  link.download = true;

  // retrieving the 'data-downloadfrom'
  // attribute-value from the changed
  // radio input:
  link.href = this.dataset.downloadfrom;

  // adding the 'allowed' class to the
  // <a> element, to show that interaction
  // is now possible:
  link.classList.add('allowed');
}

// selecting all the <input> elements with name="optradio":
let radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=optradio]'),

    // converting that NodeList into an Array, using
    // Array.from():
    radioArray = Array.from(radios),

  // retrieving the <a> element using
  link = document.querySelector('#cvLink');

// iterating over the Array of radio-inputs using
// Array.prototype.forEach() and an Arrow function:
radioArray.forEach(

  // here we bind the linkActivate() function as the
  // event-handler for the 'change' event:
  radio => radio.addEventListener('change', linkActivate)
);

// here we bind the highlightRequirements() function as
// the event-handler for the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'
// events for the <a> element:
link.addEventListener('mouseenter', highlightRequirements);
link.addEventListener('mouseleave', highlightRequirements);
```

```js
function highlightRequirements(e) {
  let clicked = this,
      required = document.querySelectorAll(clicked.dataset.required);

  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {

    if (clicked.download) {
      this.removeEventListener('mouseenter', highlightRequirements);
      this.removeEventListener('mouseleave', highlightRequirements);
      required.forEach(req => req.parentNode.classList.remove('highlight'));
    } else {
      required.forEach(req => req.parentNode.classList.add('highlight'));
    }
  } else {
    required.forEach(req => req.parentNode.classList.remove('highlight'));
  }
}

function linkActivate(e) {
  let link = document.querySelector(this.dataset.link);

  link.download = true;
  link.href = this.dataset.downloadfrom;
  link.classList.add('allowed');
}

let radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=optradio]'),
    radioArray = Array.from(radios),
    link = document.querySelector('#cvLink');

radioArray.forEach(
  radio => radio.addEventListener('change', linkActivate)
);

link.addEventListener('mouseenter', highlightRequirements);
link.addEventListener('mouseleave', highlightRequirements);
```

```css
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: limegreen;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
ul + a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
ul + a {
  color: #66c;
  cursor: no-drop;
  border: 2px solid #66c;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
ul + a.allowed {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li span.highlight {
  animation: 3s highlight;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 about-right">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
      <input type="radio"class="rad" id="radio1" name="optradio" data-downloadfrom="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=MZTFCWnRYbnlvclk" data-link="#cvLink" />
      </span>Download In PDF</li>
    <li>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
      <input type="radio" class="rad" id="radio2" name="optradio" data-downloadfrom="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=uK6ct7MZ2N6Ni1qQUFyWXM" data-link="#cvLink" />
      </span>Download In Word Doc
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
    <input type="radio" class="rad" id="radio3" name="optradio" data-downloadfrom="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0VDenJqUldud2M" data-link="#cvLink" />
    </span>Download In HTML
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="cvLink" data-required="input[name=optradio]">Download CV </a>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7jjc11wv/1/).

The above *seems* to work, though I've not verified it properly; it certainly doesn't throw any errors playing with it in the JS Fiddle demo (attached), and I think clearly shows that selecting from the radio `<input>` elements is required.

It *seems* that with the `download` attribute present that the download is initiated before the execution of the function you had attached via the `onclick` in-line event-handler (which is obtrusive JavaScript, and is why I bound events in my demo entirely in JavaScript, though I did bind a lot of data to the elements in the HTML), in this attempted solution I remove that `download` attribute and only add it, via JavaScript, once one of the radios is selected.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to have the `getCv` function return false. You need to write the return false into the onclick itself or have the result of the `getCv` function call be returned inline in the onclick itself:

```
<a href="#" id="cvLink"  download onclick="return getCv();">
```

Also, the return value of the `getCv` function should depend on whether you want the link to be executed:

```
function getCv() {
    if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
        document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=MZTFCWnRYbnlvclk";
        return true;
    }   

    else if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked) {
        document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=uK6ct7MZ2N6Ni1qQUFyWXM";
        return true;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('radio3').checked) {
     document.getElementById('cvLink').href = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0VDenJqUldud2M";
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        alert('Please Select Any Format To Download!!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add an "return false;" statement to the end of the getCv function. 
This will prevent the a from executing.

Comment: There is a `return false` there. There was a problem with the formatting, but it was there..